# Spring ORM with C3P0 or DBCP is leaking connections

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, c3p0

On the latest versions of both DBCP and C3P0, using Spring's Ibatis support,  I am running into an issue where both leak connections.

The scenario is that there is a log running SQL which locks multiple tables. This causes the connections in my pool to max out as users trigger queries which hit the locked tables. Finally, the administrator goes into MySQL and does a `kill query <id>` on the long running SQL.

If there is enough threads (in my case around 50 or more) which are waiting around for a DB thread to be checked back in to the pool, then I see something like the following in a thread dump:

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x00002aaacbb01118> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at
```

or

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
    - locked <0x00002aab0f030620> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at
```

and these threads wait around FOREVER.

This does not happen if the pool is maxed out, and only a few (around 5) threads are waiting for a free connection in the pool.

I know there is configuration that can fix this problem (setting timeout etc.), but I am interested in why this is happening in the first place? Why are the active threads not being returned to the pool, when there are 50 or more threads waiting for a connection and I kill the long running SQL?

> **Update:** I should have made it clear that I am using Spring 3.0.2 and
>   Ibatis 2.3. I use the SqlMapClientTemplate, which manages my
>   connections for me. At this point, I am beginning to think it is
>   Ibatis 2.3 not handling heavy load correctly.

Comment: Are you closing connections after executing the queries?

Comment: @BalusC I am using either a ComboPooledDataSource or BasicDataSource with Spring, so I do not manage opening c closing these connections in my Java code. Maybe Spring is the issue.

Comment: You should show some code of how you're using the connection. Just because you're using Spring to manage the data source, doesn't mean it will close your connections for you.

Comment: @Nick Actually it does, just read the source. You pass in a DataSource, to a SqlMapClientTemplate, and it manages obtaining and closing your connections.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't very clear that you were using `SqlMapClientTemplate`.

Comment: Ah I should apologize I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 5):

When using c3po, I strongly recommend trying this [feature](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients). Connection leaks usually appear when you perform database modifications outside transaction. Connection with uncommited writes cannot be reused and is lost from the pool. If you enable this debugging with reasonably long timeout, you will be able to see the stack traces with suspicious database operations.

Make sure the operations seen in the stack traces manage transactions correctly. Also monitor connection pool usage by setting c3p0 loggers to debug level.

Comment: Thanks, DBCP also has a similar config called removeAbandoned. When I set removedAbandoned, I saw I was losing connections. I still don't know why the application is losing these connections.

Comment: I am not familiar with dbcp but I have tracked down quite a few connection leaks through c3p0 debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces. Keep in mind the stack traces you will see have been generated at the point when connection was taken from the pool. This means you will see the exact call that resulted in a lost connection. Then make sure there is @Transactional or equivalent above sql call altering the database.

Comment: ah thanks, c3p0 may be more verbose than dbcp. Sadly, this area of the code doesn't support transactions.

Comment: I suppose you should be working in auto-commit mode then and situations described be me should not happen if that's the case. Would be good to confirm this and analyze a stack trace from c3p0.

Answer (score 2):

Much like what [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) asks, are you closing your connections?  They should be closed in the `finally` clause of your Java `try-catch-finally`. Wrap each `connection.close()` method in its own `try { con.close() } catch (Exception ignore) {}`

Optionally you should do so for `ResultSet` then `Statement` then `Connection` in that order.  Declare your `Connection`, `Statement`, and `ResultSet` outside your initial `try` block as `null` and instantiate in your `try` block.

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {

    con = getConnectionFromPoolMethod();

    // ...
    // instantiate your statement and result set as normal
    // make your sql call; 
    // extract data from result set to appropriate POJO

} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle your exception, log, wrap, enhance or rethrow or whatever
} finally {
    if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}
```

If you're up for it, rather than all the above code in every `finally` that wraps a SQL call, you can opt to use the [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html) utility class of [Apache Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/).

```
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
```

and apply the `closeQuietly` methods.  The `finally` block will look like this instead:

```
} finally {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(con, stmt, rs);
}
```

Comment: +1 No problem - good answer. Don't mean to nitpick but catching specific checked exceptions such as `SQLException` is considered better than practice than catching plain `Exception`.

Comment: It is better practice, but if he's new as I surmise, he might not think to import yet another class.  Editing momentarily to add option to use DbUtils.

Comment: @FredCheese My Java code isn't managing these connections. I create the data source and then pass it to a SqlMapClientTemplate, which is a Spring object. I thus, never have to manage closing  connections.

Comment: @FredCheese Unfortunately, I'm in a scenario where I don't control the SQL's that are being run on the system, so there is always a possibility of getting into this type of deadlock. I can ask my pooling lib to remove abandoned connections, but so far that is the best code fix.

Comment: Regardless, some insight as to what type of SQL call is being made by the long-running call (`Select`, `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`) might help provide you with an answer.  You may need to have some amount of leeway with the database personnel and the SQL call generation in order to repair this.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @BalusC's comment and [@JoshDM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824481/latest-c3p0-dbcp-both-leaking-connections/7825308#7825308), when you call `close()` on a `Connection` in your Java code, behind the scenes this will actually just check that connection back into your connection pool rather than physically close it. This is why it's important to always close connections through your Java code, regardless of whether the underlying JDBC driver is pooling them.

More discussion about this on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102935/c3p0-connection-checkin).